# Project to implement API for Signal messaging?

Tags: extension

Has anyone thought about creating an extension to send messages through Signal messenger APP?: https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Server/wiki/API-Protocol#sending-messages

Opposite to WhatsApp, Signal is OpenSource and allows access with an API.